# Sign precomputed hash with ECDSA or DSA

Tags: c++, digital-signature, crypto++

I'm playing around with Crypto++ signers and use the following code, straight out of the wiki:

```
ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
const Integer D(string("8964e19c5ae38669db3047f6b460863f5dc6c4510d3427e33545caf9527aafcf").c_str());
privateKey.Initialize(CryptoPP::ASN1::secp256r1(), D);
if (!privateKey.Validate(rng, 3)) {
    cerr << "ECDSA privateKey key validation failed after setting private parameter." << endl;
    return 1;
}

ECDSA<ECP,SHA256>::Signer signer(privateKey);
StringSource ss1(message, true,
    new SignerFilter(rng, signer,
        new HexEncoder(new StringSink(signature), false)
    ) // SignerFilter
); // StringSource
int slen = signature.length() / 2;
// since it's IEEE P1363 format to display r and s:
cout << signature.substr(0, slen) << "\n"
     << signature.substr(slen, slen) << endl;
```

Now, I'd like to know how I could override the SHA256 there to specify directly the digest value I want to pass to the signature algorithm.

I've digged into the [wiki](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Message_Signing) and the [doxygen documentation](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/struct_e_c_d_s_a.html), but had no success doing so. At first I thought maybe the [NullHash](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_null_hash.html) could help there, but it is really only the zero hash according to the source. I also had some hope with the [PK_MessageAccumulator](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_p_k___message_accumulator.html) but it does not appear to work as I expected.

So, is there some sort of "identity" function inheriting from the HashTransformation class that I completely missed?
If not, how would you go around building something like that allowing to specify the digest to be signed directly?

Comment: For what its worth, this is a very nasty area of the library. I helped cut-in RFC 6979, Deterministic Signatures. There was so much interaction between components (like message accumulators, formatters and the signing function) that I had a really tough time keeping things neat and tidy. It was quite painful for a me (and I have a high threshold when it comes to Crypto++).

Comment: @jww Actually what I'm trying to do is _simply_ signing/verifying **precomputed** hashes. I don't know if you know [EdDSA](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8032) and its variant called PureEdDSA. You can then describe EdDSA as simply an application of PureEdDSA to the hashed message H(M). In the same way, I'm trying to sign using "pure" ECDSA a precomputed hash I'm receiving as an input. So I was thinking maybe a HashTransformation doing nothing and outputting the message: H(M)=M might work. Would it be possible to feed such a custom HashTransformation to the ECDSA<ECP,H>::Signer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `H(M)=M` might work. Would it be possible to feed such a custom `HashTransformation` to the `ECDSA<ECP,H>::Signer`?

Yes. The program is below. It provides an `IdentityHash` class that copies input to output. It needs a template parameter to specify the hash size.

But be careful. The message is formatted after it is hashed. Really what we have is `to_sign = MF(H(M))`.

```cxx
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "secblock.h"
#include "eccrypto.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "oids.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace CryptoPP;

template <unsigned int HASH_SIZE = 32>
class IdentityHash : public HashTransformation
{
public:
    CRYPTOPP_CONSTANT(DIGESTSIZE = HASH_SIZE)
    static const char * StaticAlgorithmName()
    {
        return "IdentityHash";
    }

    IdentityHash() : m_digest(HASH_SIZE), m_idx(0) {}

    virtual unsigned int DigestSize() const
    {
        return DIGESTSIZE;
    }

    virtual void Update(const byte *input, size_t length)
    {
        size_t s = STDMIN(STDMIN<size_t>(DIGESTSIZE, length),
                                         DIGESTSIZE - m_idx);    
        if (s)
            ::memcpy(&m_digest[m_idx], input, s);
        m_idx += s;
    }

    virtual void TruncatedFinal(byte *digest, size_t digestSize)
    {
        if (m_idx != DIGESTSIZE)
            throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Input size must be " + IntToString(DIGESTSIZE));

        ThrowIfInvalidTruncatedSize(digestSize);

        if (digest)
            ::memcpy(digest, m_digest, digestSize);

        m_idx = 0;
    }

private:
    SecByteBlock m_digest;
    size_t m_idx;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    ECDSA<ECP, IdentityHash<32> >::PrivateKey privateKey;
    privateKey.Initialize(prng, ASN1::secp256r1());

    std::string message;
    message.resize(IdentityHash<32>::DIGESTSIZE);
    ::memset(&message[0], 0xAA, message.size());

    ECDSA<ECP, IdentityHash<32> >::Signer signer(privateKey);
    std::string signature;

    StringSource ss(message, true,
                        new SignerFilter(prng, signer,
                            new HexEncoder(new StringSink(signature))
                        ) // SignerFilter
                    ); // StringSource

    std::cout << "Signature: " << signature << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know it compiles and produces output. I have no idea if it is the correct output:

```
skylake:cryptopp$ g++ test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
skylake:cryptopp$ ./test.exe
Signature: cafb8fca487c7d5023fbc76ccf96f107f72a07fecca77254e8845a2c8f2ed0ee8b50b
8ee0702beb7572eaa30c8d250a7b082c79f2f02e58ccfb97d7091755e91
```

---

You can test `IdentityHash` with the following. The class `IdentityHash` did not change from the previous example. The `main` function did.

```cxx
$ cat test.cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "secblock.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace CryptoPP;

template <unsigned int HASH_SIZE = 32>
class IdentityHash : public HashTransformation
{
public:
    CRYPTOPP_CONSTANT(DIGESTSIZE = HASH_SIZE)
    static const char * StaticAlgorithmName()
    {
        return "IdentityHash";
    }

    IdentityHash() : m_digest(HASH_SIZE), m_idx(0) {}

    virtual unsigned int DigestSize() const
    {
        return DIGESTSIZE;
    }

    virtual void Update(const byte *input, size_t length)
    {
        size_t s = STDMIN(STDMIN<size_t>(DIGESTSIZE, length),
                                         DIGESTSIZE - m_idx);    
        if (s)
            ::memcpy(&m_digest[m_idx], input, s);
        m_idx += s;
    }

    virtual void TruncatedFinal(byte *digest, size_t digestSize)
    {
        if (m_idx != DIGESTSIZE)
            throw Exception(Exception::OTHER_ERROR, "Input size must be " + IntToString(DIGESTSIZE));

        ThrowIfInvalidTruncatedSize(digestSize);

        if (digest)
            ::memcpy(digest, m_digest, digestSize);

        m_idx = 0;
    }

private:
    SecByteBlock m_digest;
    size_t m_idx;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string message;
    message.resize(IdentityHash<32>::DIGESTSIZE);
    ::memset(&message[0], 'A', message.size());

    IdentityHash<32> hash;
    hash.Update((const byte*)message.data(), message.size());

    std::string digest(32, 0);
    hash.TruncatedFinal((byte*)digest.data(), digest.size());

    std::cout << "Message: " << message << std::endl;
    std::cout << " Digest: " << digest << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It produces:

```
skylake:cryptopp$ g++ test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
skylake:cryptopp$ ./test.exe
Message: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
 Digest: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it first thing tomorrow and let you know how it works. I'm a bit confused about the MF function you're mentioning, are referring to the way we convert the hash into an integer as per section 4.1.3 of Sec1v2?

Comment: Wonderful, it works perfectly and is inter-operable with OpenSSL, mbedTLS and Go! Did you take another HashTransformation as an example? I tried to do so starting from SHA3 but couldn't wrap my head around all that template-based programming. Your version is pretty neat compared to the other hash I've look at in Crypto++ code.

Comment: @Lery - The page is complete for the moment: [Adding a Hash](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Adding_a_Hash). I need to move on with some other tasks for the Crypto++ 6.0 release. I'll probably revisit the wiki page in the future. `IdentityHash` was cleaned up a bit. You might want to grab the latest. For example, it handles restart properly.